# jQuery to auto create textbox when choosing 'other' from drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a drop down full of countries. When they select Canada or US, then a separate drop down gets auto populated with states/provinces. If they choose any other country, the 2nd drop down gets populated with "Other" with a blank value.

My question is if they pick another country and th 2nd drop down get's populated with "Other", how can I auto display a textbox under the 2nd drop down, and dynamically tie it to the "Other" value. In other words, the value of the "Other"  dynamically gets populated with the textbox's value as they type. So when the form is submitted, the 2nd drop down's value gets posted with what they typed in the textbox.

Can anyone help?

Here is the jQuery plugin I am using to tie the country and state/province drop downs:
https://github.com/adam12/jquery-state-select

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery State Select Plugin Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.selectboxes.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.stateselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#country').linkToStates('#province');
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <p>
        <label>Province/State</label><br />
        <select name="province" id="province">
          <option value="">Please select a country</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Country</label><br />
        <select name="country" id="country">
          <option>Please select</option>
          <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="United States">United States</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Partial plugin code:

```
 $.fn.extend({
        linkToStates: function(state_select_id) {
      $(this).change(function() {
        var country = $(this).attr('value');
        $(state_select_id).removeOption(/.*/);
        switch (country) {
          case 'Canada':
            $(state_select_id).addOption(canadian_provinces, false);
            break;
          case 'United States':
            $(state_select_id).addOption(us_states, false);
            break;
          default:
            $(state_select_id).addOption({ '' : 'Other'}, false);
            break;
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: I suggest you post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a separate Div:

```
<div id="hiddendiv">
    <input type="text" id="othertextbox" />
</div>
```

Then:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $("#hiddendiv").hide();
});

$("#ComboBox").change(function()
{
    if($("#ComboBox option:selected").text() == "Other")
    {
        $("#hiddendiv").show();
    }
});

$("#othertextbox").change(function()
{
    $("#ComboBox").val($("#othertextbox").text());
});
```

I haven't tested this code though, so you may need to tweak it.

Comment: But how would the typed value from #othertextbox auto-populate $("#ComboBox option:selected").val()?

Comment: its not working because it is trying to select a value that is not there. "Other" option has a blank value. How can I populate that value? BTW, I tried $("#othertextbox").val() but no luck.

Comment: Hum.... If that doesn't work, I don't think thats possible... In the page that the data is sent to, you could check if the combobox is set to "other" and if it is, get the value from the text box.

Comment: Sweet, got it working. Thanks TheAdamGaskins for all the help! $("#ComboBox").find(":selected").val($(this).val());

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/uviyo4/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved a problem very similar to this and ended up writing a jQuery plugin ([jQuery.otherDropdown](http://otherdropdown.code.jstassen.com)) to collect an 'other' response for a select dropdown. It's on [GitHub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.otherdropdown) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.otherdropdown). I'll break down my approach so you can implement it your own way.

This idea is a perfect use case for jQuery in my opinion.

## The basic components

### Listen for when your 'other' options is slected

Add a `.change()` event binding on the select input.

```
$('select').change( function() {
    if(this.value === 'other') {
        // Your logic here to for when/how to prompt for user input
    }
});
```

### Listen for user input

If you choose an text input instead of a prompt (which may be a better user experience), listen for the blur event

```
// listen to a text area
$('input').blur( function() {
    if(this.value !== '') {
        // Logic to add the new option to the select
    }
});

// or bring up a prompt dialog
var value=prompt("Please indicate 'other' value:");
if(this.value !== '') {
    // Logic to add the new option to the select
}
```

### Add the new option

No matter how you choose to prompt the user for the value, adding it is as simple as creating the element via jQuery and appending it. Lastly you'll probably want to focus the value, which can be done with `.val()`

```
var $option = $('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
$('select').append($option);
$('select').val(value);
```

### Example

All of these ideas are wrapped in this plugin and might a good example you can play with and reuse to work how you need. You can see it working [here](http://otherdropdown.code.jstassen.com)

```
/**
 * @name jquery.otherdropdown
 * @description A small jQuery plugin to support a text area when selecting an 'Other' option in a dropdown
 * @version 1.0.2
 * @author Jonathan Stassen <jstassen.com>
 * @see https://github.com/TheBox193/jquery.otherdropdown
 */
$.fn.otherDropdown = function(options) {
    var $this = this;
    // Allow a different name/value to trigger, default to 'other'
    var opts = $.extend({}, {value: 'other'}, options);
    opts.name_lower = opts.value.toLowerCase();
    opts.name_upper = opts.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + opts.value.slice(1);
    opts.placeholder = opts.placeholder || opts.name_upper;

    // Bind to all change events
    $this.change( function(ev){

        // Swap in the text area if our 'other' option was chosen
        if (this.value === opts.name_lower || this.value === opts.name_upper) {
            $this.hide().after( $textInput );
            $textInput.focus();
        }
    });

    // Prepare our text input
    var $textInput = $('<input type="text" class="otherdropdown" placeholder="' + opts.placeholder + '" />');

    // Allow custom classes on the text input
    if (opts.classes) {
        $textInput.addClass(opts.classes);
    }

    // Bind to blur to swap back to select dropdown
    $textInput.blur( function(ev) {
        var value = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.remove();
        $this.show();

        if (value === '' || value === opts.name_lower || value === opts.name_upper) {
            return;
        }

        // If something was typed, create a new option with that value
        var $searchedOption = $this.children('[value="' + value + '"]');

        // If value doesn't exist, added it.
        if ( $searchedOption.length < 1 ) {
            var $option = $('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
            $this.append($option);
        }

        // Focus the value
        $this.val( value );
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#ddlSelect").change(function ()
            {                                   
                $("#divTxtGroup").empty();             
                var selectedVal = this.value;
                if (selectedVal == "Other") {
                        var newTextBoxDiv1 = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'divOther');
                        newTextBoxDiv1.after().html('<input type="text" id="txtOther">');
                        newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#divTxtGroup");                        
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         Countries
         <select id="ddlSelect" name="ddlSelect">
         <option value="-----Select-----">-----Select-----</option>
         <option value="US">US</option>
         <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
         <option value="Other">Other</option>
         </select>
         <div id='divTxtGroup'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```